# Android: Handling back button during asynctask

Tags: android

I have an Activity that shows a listview. On item click a second activity is started which runs an AsyncTask that fetches a remote URL based on which item is clicked, parses the results, then displays those results into another list view.  While the async task is running I have a "loading" view that just displays an image and text.  The problem is if I initiate the activity that runs the async task, then press back and start another instance of said activity, I get a force close.

I have tried

```
private class getlist extends AsyncTask implements OnDismissListener{
     ...
     @Override
     public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
          this.cancel(true);
     }
}
```

But the problem persists.

I have also put

```
if(!isCancelled()){
  setContentView(R.layout.list);
  ...
  etc.

}
```

into my onPostExecute call, but either this is not preventing the view from being switched, or the problem is something else.

logcat shows "unexpected resume while already resumed .. got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification"
Then a bit further down in the log, "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected"

How can I resolve this?

update:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(19379): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #2 exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(19379): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at com.metatroid.android.swim.ThreadViewer.getPosts(ThreadViewer.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at com.metatroid.android.swim.ThreadViewer$getlist.doInBackground(ThreadViewer.java:70)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at com.metatroid.android.swim.ThreadViewer$getlist.doInBackground(ThreadViewer.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(19379):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
```

Comment: Your error, if you are reading LogCat correctly, has nothing to do with any of this, but rather is a network problem when you are trying to download the data.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I've updated the question with what I believe is the correct trace

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The actual solution to this problem was to use ThreadSafeClientConnManager for the ClientConnectionManager

e.g.

```
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
```

Comment: Was encountering an "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Adapter is detached." while trying to connect to the server. This approach fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and it is now fixed, thanks you. Can you explain how did you come up with this solution? cause it seems like a patch to me and It is kind of interesting. thanks again.

Comment: I had Java.lang.IllegalException. Solved by this.

Comment: I don't see the connection between the question and this answer. Can someone explain how this solution answers the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @kilaka The ThreadSafeClientConnManager allowed an application to send  multiple connection requests. In my case I was trying to use several async tasks with the same http client which caused issues using the then default connection manager.  It's been a while, but I believe ThreadSafeClientConnManager is deprecated now..I've not kept up with Android development so no clue where things stand now.

Answer (score 6):

Do not access the activity from `doInBackground()`. It is only safe to access the activity in `onPostExecute()`, `publishProgress()`, or `onPreExecute()`, and even then only with some care to handle configuration changes, etc.

I would recommend that you make `getlist` be a static inner class, rather than a regular inner class. Manually associate the task and the activity, and break that association when the activity is destroyed or its configuration is changed. Your `onPostExecute()` and kin should then check to ensure that it has a valid activity before trying to use it.

[This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationAsync) demonstrates part of this -- handling the configuration change. It does not explicitly handle the BACK button scenario, but it does not need to, as it merely updates an activity that is off-screen.

In terms of why `getPosts()` has a NullPointerException, that is up to you to determine.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to figure out how to do that.  I have approximately four days of Java experience, so much of what I am struggling to do is quite foreign.  The NullPointerException was pointing back to a line wherein i was setting the title string from my backgrounded task.  Removing that line still leaves me an error, but now it says in logcat: "IllegalStateException: No wrapped connection" or "IllegalStateException: Adapter is detached"

Comment: @aperture: If you only have four days' of Java experience, you are going to be *way* in over your head with the stuff you are talking about here. No offense, but this stuff is going to be confusing to seasoned Java and Android developers. You may wish to start with a simpler project at the outset.

Comment: Well, everything is working really well aside from this one issue.  I can switch between other activities which also use asynctasks with no problem, and I can even switch between this troublesome activity if I wait a few seconds before launching the next instance. And of course, if i wait for the 'getPosts()' to finish before I back out of the activity, there's no problem.  I understand though, I'm very inexperienced with Java.